# How to change v-autocomplete defualt icon position?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to do something with v-autocomplete where the default position for v-autocomplete is on the right side of the field, where I want the field to have icon on the left side before the selected content.
I have tried using prepend-icon slot but that isn't working as intended.
here is sample code

```
 <v-autocomplete
          ref="city"
          v-model="city"
          :loading="showCitiesLoading"
          :disabled="showCitiesLoading"
          dense
          outlined
          clearable
          :rules="[requiredRule]"
          color="black"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="name"
          item-color="black"
          :items="citiesList"
          append-icon=""
          @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
        >
          <template #prepend-inner>
            <v-icon @click="isOpen = !isOpen">{{ isOpen ? mdiMenuDown : mdiMenuUp }}</v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
```

and also in above section I have made isOpen to false on default inside Data property.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use "prepend-icon":

```
 <v-autocomplete
      ref="city"
      v-model="city"
      :loading="showCitiesLoading"
      :disabled="showCitiesLoading"
      dense
      outlined
      clearable
      :rules="[requiredRule]"
      color="black"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="name"
      item-color="black"
      :items="citiesList"
      append-icon=""
      @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
    >
      <template slot="prepend">
        <v-icon @click="isOpen = !isOpen">{{ isOpen ? mdiMenuDown : mdiMenuUp }}</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the prepend-item slot. And remove your append-icon property too.

```html
 <v-autocomplete
          ref="city"
          v-model="city"
          :loading="showCitiesLoading"
          :disabled="showCitiesLoading"
          dense
          outlined
          clearable
          :rules="[requiredRule]"
          color="black"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="name"
          item-color="black"
          :items="citiesList"
          @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
        >
          <template #prepend-item>
            <v-icon @click="isOpen = !isOpen">{{ isOpen ? mdiMenuDown : mdiMenuUp }}</v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: you mentioned solution doesn't work, as it adds icon inside the list, Instead I want is to be on the opposite side of the default icon setup outside the field.

Comment: oh, so you can just add "prepend-icon=(your icon)"